# Is perturbation/interaction hamiltonian in interaction theory time-dependent?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, time, hamiltonian

Reading quantum field theory text, I am confused on regard to whether perturbation (or interaction equivalently) hamiltonian added to free-field hamiltonian is time-dependent or not. In Heisenberg picture, hamiltonian is an operator, so it is obviously time-dependent, but what about in Schrodinger picture? Would hamiltonian still be time-dependent overall and thus for perturbation hamiltonian?

And by QFT, I restrict to physically relevant QFTs.

Comment: If there's no explicit time dependence, the hamiltonian is constant in the Heisenberg picture since [H,H] = 0.

Comment: There can be time dependence in the interaction picture though

Answer (score 1):

The confusion may be that there are two different meanings of "time dependent".

In time-dependent perturbation theory, the interaction Hamiltonian is an explicit function of time. For example, an external force is temporarily turned on.

In introductory discussions of the Heisenberg vs. Schrodinger pictures, the Hamiltonian is time independent. It is sometimes said that either the operators or states are "time dependent", but this is different from the explicit time dependence in perturbation theory.

(In some approaches to scattering theory, both types of "time dependence" are involved.)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that in many quantum field theories the interaction Hamiltonian is time independent in the Schrödinger picture. For example, consider $\phi^4$ theory. Then in the Schrödinger picture we choose a time slice (say $t=0$) and quantize the time independent operators $\phi(\vec{x})$ and $\Pi(\vec{x})$ via their canonical commutation relations. The Hamiltonian will then be of the form
$$H=\int d^3\vec{x}\,\left(\frac{1}{2}\Pi(\vec{x})^2+\frac{1}{2}\|\vec{\nabla}\phi(\vec{x})\|^2+\frac{\lambda}{4!}\phi(\vec{x})^4\right),$$
which is time independent.

The task at hand is now to describe the time evolution of states with this Hamiltonian. This is however very difficult since the eigenvectors of this Hamiltonian are not known. However, the time evolution according to the first two terms is well known, so that one can use time dependent perturbation theory to solve for the time evolution of the whole system. In it one has a time evolution operator in the  "interaction" picture which involves the interaction Hamiltonian in the "interaction" picture. It is in this picture that the interaction becomes time dependent $V_I(t)=\int d^3\vec{x}\frac{\lambda}{4!}\phi(t,\vec{x})$, where $\phi(t,\vec{x})$ is the operator obtained by evolving $\phi(\vec{x})$ according to the free theory.

I feel much of the confusion comes from the statement that time independent perturbation theory is for time independent Hamiltonians while time dependent perturbation theory is for time dependent Hamiltonians. I think a better statement is that:

1. Time independent perturbation theory helps us find the spectrum/eigenvectors of operators which are small deviations of operators whose spectrum and eigenvectors are well known
2. Time dependent perturbation theory helps us find the time evolution induced by a Hamiltonian which is a small deviation of a Hamiltonian whose time evolution is well known. In particular, it expresses the time evolution in terms of the decomposition of the state in terms of the free theory. This is particularly useful in QFT where the states that we are interested in are asymptotically free.